# How to programmatically select GridView row so that "OnSelectedIndexChanged" event fires

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have `<asp:GridView>` that has a `select, edit, delete and insert` links within its rows. I want to trigger the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` after I insert a row.
Can someone help??

Comment: Could you explain *why* you want to do this?  I feel like there is probably a better way to do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do you have a row inserted event? If so, point the method to the OnSelectedIndexChanged method? If you don't use the parameters, just use OnSelectedIndexChanged(null,null).

Despite what I've said I'm with @jadarnel27 on this one

Comment: each row in the grid has select, edit and delete links, and the footer has insert link, selecting the inserted row is done for two purposes: 1- go to page index, and 2- to get the ID of the row, I know some other methods to accomplish that, but isn't there a piece of code that triggers the onSelectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: btw, the row inserting event is the grd_RowCommand

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply select the row by calling the `GridView.SelectRow(int rowIndex)` method, passing the index of the new row.  This will fire the `SelectedIndexChanged` event (*)

(*) To be more precise, it will first fire the `SelectedIndexChanging` event, then only fire `SelectedIndexChanged` if none of the `SelectedIndexChanging` event handlers has set `cancel` to `true`.

Comment: thanks, but how to get the index of the newly inserted record?

Comment: I cannot find GridView.SelectRow in ASP.NET 3.5 , it seems to be from .NET 4  forward

Comment: @ImanAbidi - that's right, it was added in .NET 4.  If you need it in .NET 3.5, a good approach it is to look at the .NET 4 implementation using ILSpy or similar, then replicate it.  In this case, basically it sets `GridView.SelectedIndex`, with additional code to fire the `SelectedIndexChanging` and `SelectedIndexChanged` events.

Answer (score 0):

u can fire the SelectedIndexChanged event Programmatically by

```
GridView1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
```

Comment: That's not really firing the event, that's directly invoking the event's handler.

Comment: i want to select a particular row, and then call the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event, how can I accomplish that